# Factorial recursivo

Tags: javascript

Intentando hacer el factorial de forma recursiva en Javascript, me sale 2 errores distintos, por qué sucede esto? y cómo debería realizarse?(***Según mi código***)

```js
/* 1ra forma */

function f1(n){ // Maximum call stack size exceeded
  if(n < 1) return n;
  else return f1(n * (n-1));
}


/* 2da forma */

function f2(n,neutro=1){ // Devuelve 1
 if(isNaN(n)) n = parseInt(n,10);
 if(n < 1) {return neutro;}
 else {
 neutro *= n;
 return f2(n-1)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la primera función, lo que sucede es que la condición de parada no se cumple y entra en un bucle infinito, por eso obtienes el error:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Esto pasa por que llamas recursivamente la funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
return f1(n * (n-1));
```

Al hacer esto no va disminuyendo el valor del parametro de entrada de la función como se espera, sino que aumenta por lo que nunca termina.

Por ejemplo:

```
Si n = 3 

f1(3){
  if(3<1){
    return n; //no se cumple
  }else{
   return f1(3 * (3-1)); //f1(3 * (2)) regresa 6 
  }
}
```

De tal manera que nunca se cumple la condición de parada.

Para corregir este problema envía como parámetro de entrada solo el valor decreciente a tu función, ya que de eso se trata el factorial. En código sería algo así:

```
function f1(n){
  if(n === 1) 
    return 1;
  else 
    return n * f1((n-1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu función factorial debería ser al menos parecida a esta:

```
function f1(n){
    if(n < 2) return 1;
    else
        return n*f1(n-1);
}

f1(5);
```

De esta manera vas haciendo que se vayan multiplicando decrecientemente a partir del numero pasado y terminando cuando llegue a 1 ya que al final el factorial de 0 y de 1 es 1, de esta forma el calculo seria 5*4*3*2*1, si ponias

```
return f1(n*(n-1));
```

entra en una recursividad sin fin ya que nunca **n** llegará al valor de paro, sino que ira incrementando en cada ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

En el primer ejemplo, en realidad no retornas el mismo valor si es menor que 1, en realidad debe ser igual o tener un valor de 0:

```js
function f1(n){
  //if(n < 1)
  if (n == 0 || n == 1)
     return n;
  else 
   return f1(n-1) * n
}

alert("Factorial de 4 es: " + f1(4));
```

En tu ejemplo 2, lo mismo pero además debes multiplicar por `n` el resultado de la función usando n-1 como parámetro:

```js
    function f2(n,neutro=1){ // Devuelve 1
     if(isNaN(n)) n = parseInt(n,10);
    if (n == 0 || n == 1){
        return n;
     //if (n < 1) {
     //  return neutro;
     } else {
     //neutro *= n;
     return f2(n-1) * n
     }
    }
    
      alert("Factorial de 4 es: " + f2(4));
```

---

Aquí puedes encontrar [una opción](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript) mejor optimizada, realizada por [@Marguz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97754/margus)

```js
var f = [];
function factorial (n) {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    return 1;
  if (f[n] > 0)
    return f[n];
  return f[n] = factorial(n-1) * n;
} 

 alert("Factorial de 100 es: " + factorial(100));
```

Answer (score 1):

El el primer caso te da un error **Maximum call stack size exceeded** por que la función nunca deja de llamarse esto se debe a que le restas -1 a n pero la multiplicas por n entonces el valor de n esta en un incremento exponencial por lo que jamas llegara a entrar al if y por lo tanto se quedara en un ciclo infinito.

En la segunda te da un uno por que estas retornando el neutro que lo igualas a 1 cada que se llama la función

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberias probar usar el factorial iterativo. Eso te evita tener que toparte con problemas como este. El código sería:

```js
function factorial(n) {

  var res = 1;
  
  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i += 1) {
    res *= i;
  }
  
  return res;

}
```