# No tengo claro porque da este resultado (4320)

Tags: javascript, if

No entiendo por que me da este resultado, alguien me explicaria un poco el porque de este resultado por favor?

```js
function a(n){
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return a(n - 1) * n;
  }
}

console.log(a(8)); // => 4320
```

Comment: Te da 4320 o 40,320? Podrias verificar ese dato por favor

Comment: También puede ayudar está [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/111649/12864)

Answer (score 2):

Tu función es conocida como *recursividad*  en Javascript. Y sirve para calcular el [factorial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) de un número dado.

En el caso del ejemplo, el factorial de `8`  sería `40320`.

Si le pasas el número `9` por ejemplo, daría como resultado `362880`.

La *recursividad* en Javascript es explicada por ejemplo en:

- [Recursividad (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wwbyhkx4(v=vs.94).aspx)

Y lo que ocurre en tu código es explicado con más detalle en esta pregunta de SO en Inglés:

- [Fast factorial function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3959211/5587982)

---

Esta función es más perfecta, porque maneja por ejemplo los números negativos y el cero:

```js
function factorial(num)
{
    // Si el número es menor que 0, lo rechaza
    if (num < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    // Si el número es 0, su factorial es 1
    else if (num == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    // En caso contrario, llama la función recursiva otra vez
    else {
        return (num * factorial(num - 1));
    }
}

var result = factorial(8);
console.log(result);
var result = factorial(-8);
console.log(result);
var result = factorial(0);
console.log(result);
var result = factorial(9);
console.log(result);
```